# SVG semi-circles and Arc parameter disambiguation

Tags: svg, geometry

As helpfully explained and demonstrated in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths), SVG arcs are defined in a way that is a little tricky, especially when compared to the JS Canvas `arcTo()` method.

[image: arcs]

The problem arises when I want a semi-circle in my path. In a case like this, with an angle of 180°, the two possible circles overlap, and the "large-arc flag" becomes ambiguous because it's explained as "if the arc should be greater than or less than 180 degrees" - it doesn't specify what should happen if the angle is *exactly* 180 degrees.

Until now I've "resolved" this issue through simple trial-and-error. Take a guess, did the arc go the wrong way? Try changing a flag until it works. There's only four combinations after all, it doesn't take much work.

But I'd just like to further my understanding. In a case like this, how can I know ahead of time which way my arc will go? Is there an easy way to remember this information so I don't have to resort to trial-and-error?

And on a related note, what if I want my "arc" to be a full circle? In a case like this, there are *infinitely many* possible circles that meet the criteria of "passes through the starting/ending point (same point!) and has radius R", so is this resolvable at all, or should I stick to two 180° semi-circles instead?

Comment: you can't draw a complete circle with only one arc.

Comment: I avoid 180 and 360 degree arcs by dividing them. Otherwise you are risking that your SVG will not be the same across all SVG implementations. Had a lot of problems with this in the past as I am forced to use SVG as 2D input for some special machinery and needed a lot of conversion code between CAD and other vector formats. After lot of testing and elaboration I finally give up and use only Subdivision as is the safest way and not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `sweep-flag` defines arc rotation direction. So for 180-degrees arc just choose needed semicircle with this flag. `large-arc-flag` doesn't influence in this case.

```
<svg width="325" height="325" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 0 100
           A 50 50, 0, 0, 0, 100 100
           L 125 100 Z" fill="green"/>
  <path d="M 200 100
           A 50 50, 0, 0, 1, 300 100
           L 325 100 Z" fill="green"/>
  <path d="M 0 200
           A 50 50, 0, 1, 0, 100 200
           L 125 200 Z" fill="green"/>
  <path d="M 200 200
           A 50 50, 0, 1, 1, 300 200
           L 325 200 Z" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: So basically... large-arc has no effect here, and for sweep it's 0 for anticlockwise, 1 for clockwise?

Comment: large-arc has no effect for 180-degrees arcs and has effect for other values. About sweep - yes.